# Laravel 5 Implicit Route Not Resoving

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

Editing this post entirely as I realize that I did a poor job of explaining things as they are, and to reflect a few changes already implemented.

The issue:  I have an app that has a normal front end, which works perfectly when accessed via app\public.  I've added a backend and wish to use a different master layout.  I have named the backend Crud.  I created Crud\UserController and that has the following:

```
public function __construct()
{  $this->middleware('auth'); }



public function getIndex() {
  return view('crud'); }
```

In my routes.php file I have the following:

```
Route::controller('crud', 'Crud\UserController');
```

I've tried placing that route inside and outside of the middleware group.  Neither workds.  I do have a file, crud.blade.php, that exists inside resources\views.

The issue is a 404 from apache every time I try to access app/public/crud.  Specifically, this error:

```
The requested URL /app/public/crud was not found on this server.
```

I'm at a loss as to why the server is unable to find the route to crud.blade.php

ETA:  The apache access log just shows a normal 404 when I attempt to access this page.  The apache error log shows no errors.

Answer (score 0):

The view() is suppose to point to a view file, that is something like example.blade.php which should contain the content you want displayed when the localhost:app/crud is visited. Then you can do view('example') without the .blade.php.
From your code, change

```
class UserController extends Controller{
    //Route::controller('crud', 'Crud\UserController');

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function getIndex() {  
        return view('/');
    }
}
```

to

```
class UserController extends Controller{
    //Route::controller('crud', 'Crud\UserController');

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function getIndex() {  
        return view('crud'); // crud being your view file
    }
}
```

Comment: That change makes sense and I'll keep it, but it did not fix the problem.

Comment: How do you come about localhost://app/crud?

Comment: Also what error message is it displaying along the 404

Comment: The requested URL /app/public/crud was not found on this server.

Comment: @BlindFish Is the error message come from `Laravel` or plain text. And make sure you have file named `crud.php` or `crud.blade.php` inside `view` folder.

Comment: @Blind Fish is your URL pointing to Laravel public directory?

Comment: I think the error is coming from your local server (LAMP) and not Laravel

Comment: Editing the original post to reflect the current situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing concepts. Trying to get here will always throw an error:

```
localhost://app/crud
```

To enter your app, just try to access:

```
http://localhost
```

appending a route you registered in your routes.php file. In your example, It'd be:

```
http://localhost/crud
```

If you register

```
Route::get('/crud', 'Crud\UserController@index')
```

Then you need an Index method inside UserController, which should return a view (in your example)

```
class UserController extends Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index() 
    {  
        return view('crud');
    }
}
```

P.S: about Implicit controllers, you have the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#implicit-controllers).

Comment: Technically, it is localhost://app/public/crud.  I'm running laravel on a traditional LAMP stack that hosts several dev sites, but this is one is my laraval tinkering project.  I access the index of the site, which works swimmingly, by localhost://app/public/index.php.

Comment: PS: I've read the implicit controllers docs about fifty times.  I'm quite certain that I'm over thinking this, I'm just not sure where.

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting what you need. If you wanna use implicit controllers, the line Route::controller('crud', 'Crud\UserController'); should go inside your routes.php file, not inside your controller. And if you do so, you don't need to use the line Route::get('/crud', 'Crud\UserController@Index');

Comment: It's throwing a 404 because if you use get('/crud', 'Crud\UserController@Index') you need an index method in your controller and if you use the getIndex method, you need the Route::controller declaration inside the routes.php. You're mixing both

Comment: I have "Route::controller('crud', 'Crud\UserController'); " in the middleware group of my routes.php.  I have " public function getIndex()
   {
      return view('crud');
   }" inside my UserController.  I have crud.blade.php inside of my views folder.  And I get the 404.

Comment: Editing the original post to reflect the current situation.

Comment: I always symlink a shorthand of my apps name to the public folder of the app for easy access. Example project: `example_app`, I would symlink `ln -s /var/www/html/example_project/public /var/www/html/example` and then access my project via `http://localhost/example`. Makes my life easier and makes routing simpler :P